# tomcat8 - Main java HttpServlet works, but ServletContextListener cannot access mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using ubuntu 16.04, tomcat8, mysql 5.7.12, and activeMQ for some things. I have googled alot. I don't generally find examples about my exact situation, but commonly for older tomcat and mysql versions, etc. I basically get this error when the context listener is working (every 15 mins it checks for certian activity). I am using the IntelliJ community edition and maven.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env/jdbc/acnn] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at org.davidliebman.desktop.audio.ACNNDataBase.getConnection(ACNNDataBase.java:87)
at org.davidliebman.desktop.audio.ACNNDataBase.doUpdate(ACNNDataBase.java:199)
at org.davidliebman.desktop.audio.ACNNDataBase.deleteUserPlaying(ACNNDataBase.java:386)
at org.davidliebman.server.audio.ACNNContextListener$DB.run(ACNNContextListener.java:39)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

'acnn' is the name of my database. below is my web.xml file in my war:

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    metadata-complete="false"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

<servlet>
       <servlet-name>ACNNServer</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org..server.audio.ACNNServer</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>ACNNServer</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/ACNNServer</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org..server.audio.ACNNContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<resource-ref>
    <description>ACNN DB</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/acnn</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

here is the  section of my conf/server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

 <Resource name="jdbc/acnn" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="xxx" password="xxx" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acnn"
            removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
            removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
            logAbandoned="true" />

<ResourceLink name="jdbc/acnn"
            global="jdbc/acnn"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

here is the matching part of the conf/context.xml file

```
<Context allowLinking="true">

<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource name="jdbc/acnn" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="xxx" password="xxx" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acnn"
            removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
            removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
            logAbandoned="true" />

<ResourceLink name="jdbc/acnn"
         global="jdbc/acnn"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</Context>
```

finally in despiration I copied the material to the META-INF/context.xml file. I think there it is ignored. Not sure.

```
<Context allowLinking="true">


<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>


<Resource name="jdbc/acnn" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="xxx" password="xxx" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acnn"
            removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
            removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
            logAbandoned="true" />

<ResourceLink name="jdbc/acnn"
         global="jdbc/acnn"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</Context>
```

the actual code, which works when run from the HttpServlet and not from the ServletContextListener is here:

```
    public class ACNNDataBase {
    ...

    private Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/acnn");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        return conn;
    }
    public void getVersion() {

        String command = "SELECT VERSION()";
        String rs = doQuery(command);
        System.out.println(rs);

    }

    public String doQuery(String command) {
        try {
            Connection con = getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(command);

            String value = "";

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                value = rs.getString(1);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    ...
}
```

here is the class that calls the db function:

```
public class ACNNContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    private int FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DB(), 0, FIFTEEN_MINUTES * 60 * 1000);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }

    class DB extends TimerTask{

        public void run () {

            ACNNDataBase db = new ACNNDataBase();
            db.getVersion();
        }
    }
}
```

That's everything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly put the class definition and  method signature in the context that call the datasource.

Comment: which method calls the `getConnection()`??

Comment: Your case is not clear, you have put a full functional context listener to be able to help you.(you can make an example that re-produce the same scenario and remove your private business logic)

Comment: I have added code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested it on my machine, and the main trick is:

```
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");             
            DataSource d = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/acnn");
```

**Details :** 
you have to do the following only :
 - Keep only `META-INF/context.xml` for the configurations.
 - Keep the section in `web.xml`.
 - Remove all your config from(restore it to defaults) tomcat/conf/web.xml , tomcat/conf/server.xml and tomcat/conf/context.xml

-In your listener, get connection as in this example:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ACNNContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private int FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DB(), 0, FIFTEEN_MINUTES * 60 * 1000);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }

    class DB extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
                Context envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");

                DataSource d = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/acnn");
                Connection connection = d.getConnection();
                connection.close();
                System.out.println("Done");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Also , be sure to put your tomcat jdbc-driver in tomcat/lib folder
  **EDIT :**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
>   <listener>
>       <listener-class>
>           a.b.c.ACNNContextListener
>       </listener-class>
>   </listener>
>   <resource-ref>
>       <description>ACNN DB</description>
>       <res-ref-name>jdbc/acnn</res-ref-name>
>       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>   </resource-ref>
> </web-app>
> ```

My full META-INF/context.xml:

```
    <Context allowLinking="true">       
    <Resource name="jdbc/acnn" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="root" password="123456" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scd" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"        removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true" />
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/acnn" global="jdbc/acnn" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

Comment: this is not working. It's still giving me the same error when I try to get 'envCtx'. I am following the example and trying to get the context in the 'run()' method. any other suggestions?

Comment: put your mysql jdbc driver in %tomcat%\lib folder , if not working , please paste the exception here

Comment: I have updated my answer , kindly follow the steps one by one, and it should work. Please let me know. (Note , I have already tested in tomcat 7 and tomcat 8)

Comment: For me , i am using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar`

Comment: During context initialization not all environment will be available in tomcat (However this is tomcat issue only , if you try wildfly you will be fine).
Regarding your question about maven dependency , no , they shouldn't be the same , however , configuring maven dependency for mysql is not required if you choose to use tomcat datasource.

Comment: none of the above has solved my basic problem. What should be the contents of the /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml file? I have deleted it for now. I have a WEB-INF/web.xml in my war. HttpServlet still works and ContextListener doesn't.

Comment: Check my updated answer which includes my full web.xml

Comment: Also , i have included my full META-INF/context.xml

Comment: can you have only one 'listener' ? In my war I actually have two. Do you think I should try tomcat7? I may have time for that tomorrow.

Comment: I would recommend fresh copy of tomcat , and build new fresh example and try the steps in my answer (and most probably it will work) , to insure that you don't have another hidden issues in your application/environment.

Comment: Also , i have already tested my example on both tomcat7/8 .Regarding two listeners,  no , this will not cause any problem assuming that the listeners doesn't through any exceptions.